# No output on `gpg --fingerprint` when retrieving the key for Launchpad

Tags: 10.04, ppa, launchpad, gnupg

I'm trying to sign ubuntu code conduct for creating my own ppas. I run the `gpg --fingerprint` command on my server as asked by the launchpad how-to. The problem is - there is no output whatsoever. Here's the output I got when I ran the command for the very first time:

```
$ gpg --fingerprint
gpg: directory `/home/eimantas/.gnupg' created
gpg: new configuration file `/home/eimantas/.gnupg/gpg.conf' created
gpg: WARNING: options in `/home/eimantas/.gnupg/gpg.conf' are not yet active during this run
gpg: keyring `/home/eimantas/.gnupg/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /home/eimantas/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
```

The consequent command invocations give no output at all. I even tried redirecting the output to the file (thinking it checks for stdout type), but still - no results. Where does the output go? Should I configure something extra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, there are no keys on your keyring. Those messages can be ignored, if you remove your `~/.gnupg` directory, those messages will be visible again.

You need to create the GPG key first, both a GUI and CLI way are described on the help page of Launchpad: https://help.launchpad.net/YourAccount/ImportingYourPGPKey